# Orbot DNS leak problem

Tags: orbot, dns

I tried to use Orbot on my Android phone in VPN mode (no extra settings added or anything). It turned out that it leaks DNS with Chrome browser (I checked it with dnsleak.com). Is it possible to fix this / is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome browser with as you said no extra settings is not made to connect through Tor. Orbot works through some apps like Orweb, DuckDuckGo Search Engine app, etc
Are you sure your Chrome is connecting through Orbot?